# QML FileDialog and Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, qml

I decided to try working in VS code.
The main project I'm working with uses Qt 5.15.2.
I ran into a Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to use a FileDialog with selectFolder set to true

This problem only occurs when using VS code in Qt Creator everything works

I found a similar question, but there the problem itself was solved

```
    FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Please choose a file"
    folder: shortcuts.home
    selectFolder: true
    
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("You chose: " + fileDialog.fileUrls)
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Canceled")
    }
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess I would told you that maybe OS specific plugins are not loaded by Qt. Set Environment variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and then compare output from both runs to see if the same plugins are loaded in both cases (and if there are no errors). If plugins can not be loaded you can always add missing directory by specifying QT_PLUGIN_PATH to something like C:/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/plugins/

Comment: @bialy I tried it on a running machine and compared the output in the console. There is no difference.